# Given a variable of double type, how to output it with 3 digits after the decimal point in C

Tags: c

```
void avg(int sum, int count){

double result = sum/count;
printf("running average is %d/%d = %f\n",sum,count,result);

}
```

//Here function avg returns avg of sum and total no. of inputs, I need to display the output of the double result variable to 3 digits after the decimal

Answer (score 0):

Just checked we can do by:

```
printf("%.3f",result);
```

Comment: But you'll always get `X.000` because you have done *integer division*. You need `double result = (double)sum / count;`